# what should be the value of counter such that everytime I run the application it increases dynamically without changing database

Tags: java

what should be the value of counter such that everytime the application is run it increases dynamically without changing database.

```
    @Component
    public class JdbcDaoImpl {
    static PreparedStatement ps;
    static int counter = 0;

    ResultSet rs;
    ResultSet rs2;
     Connection conn = null;

     private Connection getConnection() throws SQLException,   ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException{

         if(conn==null)
         {
        try {

            String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver";
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527//db2");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            throw new RuntimeException(e);

        }

        }
        return conn;

    }

    public Circle getCircle(int circleId) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
//  Circle circle= null;
        //int instance = 0;
        try {

            conn = getConnection();


            ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM circle where id =?");

            ps.setInt(1, circleId);

            Circle circle = null;
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {



                circle = new Circle(circleId, rs.getString("name"));

            }
            if(circle!=null)
            {
                counter++;
                ps= conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE circle set name=? where id=?");


                String name=("dav"+(counter));


                ps.setString(1, name);
                ps.setInt(2, circleId);
                ps.executeUpdate();
                conn.commit();



            }
            return circle;
        } finally {
            rs.close();
            ps.close();
            conn.close();

        }
    }
```

Comment: I want value of counter like 1,2,3 and not 1,1,1 it should be increemented everytime code is run

Comment: answer should be dav0 , dav1, dav2

Comment: yes it is executing.

Comment: You need to persist `counter` in the database (or somewhere in a file, or in java.util.prefs, or *anywhere*) Nothing is automatically persisted between different runs of the java binary; if you want to persist it you need to do it yourself.

Comment: @ErwinBolwit -thats what I wrote I dont want to specify in database ,Is ther any means by which I can do over consel itself

Comment: @PalakChugh And that's what I explained, you need to explicitly persist it somewhere. There's no way that this will magically happen by itself.

Comment: ok then,  I will do by that thanks @ErvinBolwit

Comment: thanks @VinodMadyalkar

Comment: @PalakChugh - Lol. For what?. BTW you should probably write the value of counter to a file..

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar I have already tried that. I wanted to know any other mean, coz I was assigned to do by any other method. This is perhaps not possible.

Comment: @PalakChugh - Unfortunately no.. There is no other way